# WP Customizer: checkbox value unreachable with get_option

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, themes, wordpress-theming

this is my code:

```
function vds_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogname' )->transport         = 'postMessage';
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogdescription' )->transport  = 'postMessage';
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'header_textcolor' )->transport = 'postMessage';

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'blog_settings' , array(
            'title' => __( 'Blog settings', 'vds' ),
            'priority' => 30
        ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'vds[blog_show_commentslink_in_overview]', array(
            'default' => '1',
            'type' => 'option'
        ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'blog_show_commentslink_in_overview', array(
            'label' => __( 'Show comments link in blog overview?' ),
            'section' => 'blog_settings',
            'settings' => 'vds[blog_show_commentslink_in_overview]',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'std' => '1'
        ) );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'vds_customize_register' );
```

I tried the following code to get the value in the templates:

```
get_option( 'vds[blog_show_commentslink_in_overview]' );
get_option( 'blog_show_commentslink_in_overview' );
get_theme_mod( 'vds[blog_show_commentslink_in_overview]' );
get_theme_mod( 'blog_show_commentslink_in_overview' );
```

none of them worked :/ Why is that? The actual value is stored I guess because if I deactivate the checkbox in the customizer and reload the customizer, the checkbox is unchecked so it shouldve saved that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$variable = get_theme_mod( 'vds[blog_show_commentslink_in_overview]' ) == '1' ? '// what to run' : '';

echo $variable;
```

This is what i use.